# how to set up a github repo for my project

Tags: github

I am new to **Github** and want to setup a account for my project that I will be writing it in **Ruby on Rails**. I am using **Virtual Box** and set my VM OS on **Ubuntu**. I have created a Github account and a new Repo for my project test. These are the steps I went through so far:

```
    cd test
    git config --global user.name ’My Name’
    git config --global user.email ’Myemailaddress’
    git init
    touch README
    add README
    git remote add origin git@github.com:myusername/myreponame.git
    git push origin master
```

till these steps everything is fine and then I created my app with

```
    rails new test -T
```

Now after this step I am really not sure what to do next. Should I add all my files and directories to Github Repo or only those that I am going to modify. And what is the git syntax to add all files and directories together? How to commit and save the commit? I really appreciate any suggestion...

Comment: http://gitimmersion.com/ can be usefull if you are new to Git.

Answer (score 2):

Now, import your project into GIT, like so:

```
git add .
git commit
```

http://www.manniwood.com/starting_a_project_with_git.html

You may want to push your commits to github as well:

```
git push
```

But, as noted above, you're better off getting through a tutorial: in order to be able to benefit from git, you need to understand what you're doing, and simple answers like "do X" are not of much help here.

My favourite is [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book)— you'll need to work through it from start to [2.5 Git Basics - Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) at least.

Answer (score 2):

just do it in your terminal/comment prompt

```
~/.ssh
    ls
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your register mail-id"
    ls
    vim id_rsa.pub

copy the manually keys 4 line and paste it in git Account settings--> ssh key--> add key

git config --global user.name "your register Name"
    git config --global user.email "your register mail-id"

    mkdir ~/YourFolderName
    cd ~/YourFolderName

    git init

select your user name in that you created repository
from that select currently upload repository and
select from git@github.com:registerName/ repository_name.git

    git clone git@github.com:registerName/repository_name.git

    git add *
    cd repository_name

    git add *
    git commit -m "repository_name"
    git push origin master


    cd
    cd ~/.ssh
```